# Frame doesn't obey HeightRequest

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Can you guys please explain why the `Frame` doesn't respect the HeightRequest or WidthRequest?

Using those properties in other controls it works as expected.

For example, in this XAML I'm using a `Frame` and a `BoxView`:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
             HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
             Padding="10">
    <Frame VerticalOptions="Center"
           HeightRequest="5"
           WidthRequest="5"
           BackgroundColor="Red"/>
    <BoxView VerticalOptions="Center"
             HeightRequest="5"
             WidthRequest="5"
             Color="Blue"/>
</StackLayout>
```

And the result is:

[image: xaml sample]

There is a big difference between the Frame's size and box's size, but it shouldn't have.

Comment: What if you set Frame's Padding "0"? Because Frames have a default "20" Padding.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Frame has a default padding of 20. Set `Padding="0"`.

See the remarks here: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Frame/

Comment: I had this problem too, thanks. A default padding of 20... bizarre

Comment: @Gerry Yeah, I'm also not sure why they decided on that. But I can only guess the reason why they left it, and haven't changed it, is because it would affect a lot of apps that simply use that default value, if they were to update Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Every damn time I use a Frame I forget this stupid default.

Comment: I set a default style (i do a similar one for grid row/column spacing)

`<Style TargetType="Frame" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True"><Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" /></Style>`

Comment: @Jammer you shouldn't have to remember it.  Stuff like this in Xamarin drives me absolutely crazy.

Comment: This was driving me crazy too. Another frustrating thing about Xamarin.Forms is that it ignores heightRequest and WidthRequest when Horizontal/Vertical options are set to "Fill" and "Fill" is the default setting! So you can go through all the trouble of setting specific heights and widths and XF will just ignore you. If you want to set the sizes manually you *also* have to remember to override the layout options default values.

Comment: Yes, don't forget the default "Fill" @Sean commented.